# Socket.io is failing in firefox and IE

Tags: socket.io

I am using sockets.io that is working fine on Web Chrome Safari mobile Web Android - IOS and also installed as apps on Android & IOS.

However it fails in Firefox & IE.

Code as follows:

```
function connectSocket(){
socket = io.connect('http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8124', {'reconnect': true,'reconnection delay':        500,'max reconnection attempts': 50 });


socket.on('connect', function () { 
//app.jGrowl('sockets connected');
socket.emit('subscribe', {schoolNewsUpdated:'schoolNewsUpdated'});
app.setProperty(['labelConnected'],'fontcolor','white');
app.setValue('labelConnected','Connected');
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () { 
//app.jGrowl('disconnected ');
app.setProperty(['labelConnected'],'fontcolor','red');
app.setValue('labelConnected','NotConnected');
});   


}

function handler_actionBtnStart_onClick(mouseev){
connectSocket();    
}

function handler_actionBtnDisconnect_onClick(mouseev){
socket.socket.disconnect(); 
}

function handler_actionBtnReConnect_onClick(mouseev){
socket.socket.reconnect();  
}
```

I have created a basic test app here http://acft.ws/tvnu using only the above code.

I've search for socket.io not working in firefox but don't see any issues.

So hopefully I am doing something wrong in my code that only firefox & IE sees ?

MrWarby

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browsers console?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I should have used that (new to all the debugging on web) mainly done windows in delphi. It says Blocked loading mixed active content. The app platform is on a https site and the socket io is on our server http. I uploaded the app to our server and it is working okay.

Comment: The problem is due to the mix in protocols - I've encountered the same error in those browsers.